# Hover effect buggy

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm really bad at explaining, but here's a gif how it looks like when hovered:

[image]

I need the arrow to come from left only, when hovered (not like in the gif).
You'll get what I mean when you look at the gif.

Here's my CSS:

```
.nav-background .nav-content .nav-li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Lato Black", sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-background .nav-content .nav-li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
}


.nav-background .nav-content .nav-li a:hover {
  background: url("../img/arrow-right-white.png") no-repeat left;
  background-size: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

If somebody could help, I'd appreciate it very much! :)

Comment: please add a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will help us to help you.

Comment: Try remove background-size: 50px; from .nav-background .nav-content .nav-li a:hover or you can use small image of arrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this problem because you use transition for all properties. Try to use transition only for background position :

```
-webkit-transition:background-position 1s ease-in;  
-moz-transition:background-position 1s ease-in;  
-o-transition:background-position 1s ease-in;  
transition:background-position 1s ease-in;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPnuN/535/)